# How to get the maximum value by id over the last 4 quarters in r data.table?

Tags: r, data.table, aggregate

I have a dataset with id's and states. I need to get the maximum status over the last 4 quarters. As an example, I created this table:

```
library(data.table)
library(zoo)

DT = 
  data.table(id=c("1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","2"),
             date=as.yearqtr(c("2015Q1", "2014Q4", "2014Q3", "2014Q2", "2014Q1", "2013Q4","2013Q3","2013Q2","2015Q2")),
             status=c(0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0))
```

I want to get the maximum value for `status` over the last 4 quarters available:

```
DT = 
data.table(id=c("1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","2"),
           date=as.yearqtr(c("2015Q1", "2014Q4", "2014Q3", "2014Q2", "2014Q1","2013Q4","2013Q3","2013Q2","2015Q2")),
           status=c(0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0),
           Max_status=c(0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0))
```

Does anyone have any clue to do that neatly and quickly in data.table? I tried something like this:

```
DT[,Date_1yPrior:=date-1]
DT[,Max_Status:=max(status[date>=Date_1yPrior & date<=Date_1yPrior]),by='id']
```

but the j and i refers are not correct. I would prefer a `data.table` solution.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: which is this func as.yearqtr() ? which package?

Comment: @joel.wilson just edited the question with the package load. ``zoo`` is for as.yearqtr()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does the trick:

```
library(zoo)
library(data.table)
DT[, date_num := as.numeric(date)]
DT[, NextStatus1Q := .SD[match(date_num - .25, .SD$date_num), status], by=id]
DT[, NextStatus2Q := .SD[match(date_num - .5, .SD$date_num), status], by=id]
DT[, NextStatus3Q := .SD[match(date_num - .75, .SD$date_num), status], by=id]
DT[, NextStatus4Q := .SD[match(date_num - 1, .SD$date_num), status], by=id]
DT[,MaxStatus:=max(NextStatus1Q,NextStatus2Q,NextStatus3Q,status,0,na.rm=T),by=c('id','date')]
#DT[,MaxStatus:=max(NextStatus1Q,NextStatus2Q,NextStatus3Q,NextStatus4Q,status,0,na.rm=T),by=c('id','date')] # If you also want 4q (actually 5 quarters back)
```

Create new columns where you lookup the value 1-3 quarters ago and after that select the max.

Answer (score 3):

Using `zoo::rollapplyr`

```
DT[order(id, date), max_status:=rollapplyr(status, FUN=max, width=4, fill=0, partial=TRUE), id]  
DT

#   id    date status max_status
#1:  1 2015 Q1      0          0
#2:  1 2014 Q4      0          0
#3:  1 2014 Q3      0          0
#4:  1 2014 Q2      0          1
#5:  1 2014 Q1      0          1
#6:  1 2013 Q4      0          1
#7:  1 2013 Q3      1          1
#8:  1 2013 Q2      0          0
#9:  2 2015 Q2      0          0
```

Comment: It should really depend on the date, it could for example happen that there are gaps in the data and then this wouldn't work, right?

Comment: In that case, fill in the missing year-quarter instances.